# Convert List of Objects to Json in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with [JqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) with ASP.NET MVC 4.

This is a sample data from [one of the examples](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/date-axes.php) from Jqplot

`var line1 = [['2008-06-30 8:00AM', 4], ['2008-7-30 8:00AM', 6.5], ['2008-8-30 8:00AM', 5.7], ['2008-9-30 8:00AM', 9], ['2008-10-30 8:00AM', 8.2]];`

the first value in the pair is DateTime and other is value.

Now I am trying to get value **like this** from controller instead, I am using **Web Api** Controller

my action is as follows

```
public List<Stats> GetGraphData()
{
    var stats = new List<Stats>
                    {
                        new Stats {Date = DateTime.Now, Value = 4},
                        new Stats {Date = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1), Value = 11},
                        new Stats {Date = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2), Value = 5},
                        new Stats {Date = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3), Value = 7},
                    };
    return stats;
}
```

but the value that returned is

> [Object { Date= "2012-11-08T16:52:04.5047592+05:30",  Value=4}, [Object { Date="2012-11-08T16:52:04.5047592+05:30",  Value=4}, ...

So I decided to try **JSON.stringify()** on it which gave the following...

> [{"Date":"2012-11-08T16:52:04.5047592+05:30","Value":4},{"Date":"2012-12-08T16:52:04.5047592+05:30","Value":11},{"Date":"2013-01-08T16:52:04.5047592+05:30","Value":5},{"Date":"2013-02-08T16:52:04.5047592+05:30","Value":7}]

How do I get the format like the one shown below ?
`[['2008-06-30 8:00AM', 4], ['2008-7-30 8:00AM', 6.5], ['2008-8-30 8:00AM', 5.7], ['2008-9-30 8:00AM', 9], ['2008-10-30 8:00AM', 8.2]];`

Please help me on this.

*Note : Please feel free to edit the Title of my question, I could'nt think of anything else :P*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using objects instead of arrays, you can do something like this: instead of this:

```
new Stats {Date = DateTime.Now, Value = 4},
```

Try this:

```
new String[] { DateTime.Now.ToString(), "4" },
```

Of course change the `List<Stats>` to `List<String[]>`

Another option would be to flatten the object into an array in Javascript once you get it. Let's say you put the data coming form the server into a variable called `serverArray`, this will look like an array of objects:

```
var serverArray = [{Date: "2012-11-08T16:52:04.5047592+05:30", Value: 4}, { .... }, etc. etc. ];
```

Then you can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map this array into another array:

```
results = serverArray.map(function (obj) { return [obj.Date, obj.Value]; });
```

results will look like this (note the squqre brackets to indicate an array and the absence of the object keys, Date and Value):

```
[["2012-11-08T16:52:04.5047592+05:30", 4], [......], etc. etc. ];
```

and then you can use "results" in you plotting being in the same format as the sample data.

Comment: `List<String[]>` did the job. Answer Accepted :) can you tell me more about `serverArray.map` approach pls..

Comment: With serverArray I intended a random name for the data coming from the server. I updated the answer to make things clearer.